# How do I make this regular expression not match anything after forward slash /

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression:

```
/^www\.example\.(com|co(\.(in|uk))?|net|us|me)\/?(.*)?[^\/]$/g
```

It matches:

```
www.example.com/example1/something
```

But doesn't match

```
www.example.com/example1/something/
```

But the problem is that, it matches: I do not want it to match:

```
www.example.com/example1/something/otherstuff
```

I just want it to stop when a slash is enountered after ***"something"***. If there is no slash after ***"something"***, it should continue matching any character, except line breaks.

I am a new learner for regex. So, I get confused easily with those characters

Comment: Try `^www\.example\.(com|co(?:\.(?:in|uk))?|net|us|me)(?:\/([^\/]+))?(?:\/([^\/]+))?$`

Comment: So do you want only two slashes to be allowed in your url?

Comment: Ok. I was confused by the string "something", I thought you wanted to forbid the third slash only when appearing after a specific string.

Comment: What do you mean by `1,2,3,4,,6`?

Comment: Then use `^www\.example\.(com|co(?:\.(?:in|uk))?|net|us|me)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^www\.example\.(?:com|co(?:\.(?:in|uk))?|net|us|me)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxgOqT/3)

The `(.*)?` part in your pattern matches any zero or more chars, so it won't stop even after encountering two slashes. The `\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)` part in the new pattern will match two parts after slash, and capture each part into a separate group (in case you need to access those values).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `www\.example\.` - `www.example.` string
- `(?:com|co(?:\.(?:in|uk))?|net|us|me)` - `com`, `co.in`, `co.uk`, `co`, `net`, `us`, `me` strings
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Your answer or that person's answer. I am confused

Comment: I can't decide yet

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana If you need to access the capturing group values (those after slashes), my solution is what you need. If that's not important, select any you like.

Comment: Yours seems more clearer to me. because I am a newbie

Comment: `?:` vs `?` in regex?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions), it is used to group patterns in order to either use alternation `|` operator or quantify them. The value matched is not stored as a submatch in the match object. `?` is just a quantifier that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the pattern it modifies.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^www\.example\.(?:com|co(?:\.(?:in|uk))?|net|us|me)(?:\/[^\/]+){2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0sxKu/1)

This will match following URL:

```sh
www.example.co.uk/example1/something
```

Comment: Can you make it so that it doesn't match 1,2,3,4,,6

Comment: Please suggest complete URL that don't want to match

Comment: I do not want to match: `www.example.com` `www.example.com/` `www.example.com/example1` `www.example.com/example1/` `www.example.com/example1/something/`

Comment: So you just want to match `www.example.co.uk/example1/something` ?

Comment: Thanks that worked out. I can't accept answer because there is cooldown

Comment: jfyi If you want to capture part after domain name use: `^www\.example\.(?:com|co(?:\.(?:in|uk))?|net|us|me)((?:\/[^\/]+){2})$`

Comment: I am already confused about these. .... Just stop for a moment